# Trace context (distributed tracing) for Firestore Trigger functions

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-trace

Is it possible to attach a trace context to firestore triggers so that its easy to figure out the application flow?

Currently we are triggering some pubsub events on data change in firestore triggers.

Wondering if there is a way to pass a context so that we can group all the spans for an action.

Comment: have you figured out a way to do this?

Comment: Nope! They doesn't seem to add the required trace headers for the triggers.